# How to use the running Thread in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am having problem in following code

```
 def create
  mythreads=[]
  mythreads=Thread.list
  @device_id=params[:data]['device_id']

    if mythreads[@device_id].alive?
      //I want this stuff
    else
       mythreads[@device_id]=Thread.new(arg) { savedata(params[:data])  }
    end

 end

  def savedata(data)
     Model.create(data)
  end
```

- Data is coming by post request
- I want to **create separate threads for each device_id if it is not created**
- And if it is **already created I want to use the same thread to store the data**
- If the thread is alive what code should I write in **if condition's true block**

  to pass the data to the existing thread???

  so that the **savedata() function is called and data is stored**

Comment: You should not do this in Rails. Also, explain `why` you would like to do this, as it seems to be a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Then what is your suggesion ???

Comment: As I said, fist explain why you would like to do this, as it's very likely that there is a better (and funcional) way of doing this using Rails.

Comment: I have many device's. they send  their data continuously using http  post requests at some seconds delay...I want to save that data

Comment: You don't need threads for this, just save inside the controller that serves this call.

Comment: if i have 1000 devices . and they send data at 10 seconds delay then 1000*10=10000 requests in 10 seconds. Is it possible????... if nat please tell the alternative

Comment: Of course it is, benchmark your servers, see how many servers are needed to serve all these requests and then have as many servers running your app as needed to serve all requests.

Comment: Can you explain in details.I not understand benchmarking of servers..